# Show/Hide element on focus/blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this code snippet shows an animated password input field. If you click in the input field (onFocus) an toggle eye icon appears to show or hide the password. After you leave the input field focus (onBlur) the eye icon disappers. Now my problem is, that the toggle eye icon is not clickable right now. I don't know how to solve his.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

```js
  function showeye() {
 var string = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback"></i>';
         document.getElementById('showhide').innerHTML = string;
      }
 
      function hideeye() { 
 var string = '';
         document.getElementById('showhide').innerHTML = string;
      }

var $inputItem = $(".js-inputWrapper");
  $inputItem.length && $inputItem.each(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
  $input = $this.find(".formRow--input"),
  placeholderTxt = $input.attr("placeholder"),
  $placeholder;
  
$input.after('<span class="placeholder">' + placeholderTxt + "</span>"),
  $input.attr("placeholder", ""),
  $placeholder = $this.find(".placeholder"),
  $input.val().length ? $this.addClass("active") : $this.removeClass("active"),

  $input.on("focusout", function () {
    $input.val().length ? $this.addClass("active") : $this.removeClass("active");
  }).on("focus", function () {
    $this.addClass("active");
  });
});


// toggle password visibility
$('#password + .glyphicon').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-eye-close').toggleClass('glyphicon-eye-open'); // toggle our classes for the eye icon
  $('#password').togglePassword(); // activate the hideShowPassword plugin
});
```

```css
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing: border-box;}html,body{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;}.wrapper{width:400px; max-width:80%;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<style type="text/css">
.clearable-input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.clearable-input > input {
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}
.clearable-input:hover > [data-clear-input] {
  display: block;
}
.clearable-input > [data-clear-input] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clearable-input > input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
      .formRow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.formRow--item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.formRow--input {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px 11px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px #95989a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #2c3235;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.formRow--input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.formRow--input-wrapper.active .placeholder {
  top: -5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #fd999a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}
.formRow--input-wrapper.active .formRow--input:not(:focus):not(:hover) ~ .placeholder {
  color: #fec8c9;
}
.formRow--input-wrapper .formRow--input:focus, .formRow--input-wrapper .formRow--input:hover {
  border-color: #fd999a;
}
.formRow .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #95989a;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all, .2s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
   #password + .glyphicon {
   cursor: pointer;
   pointer-events: all;
 }

#wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25vh;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hideshowpassword/2.1.1/hideShowPassword.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<fieldset class="formRow">
<div class="formRow--item">
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<label for="password" class="formRow--input-wrapper js-inputWrapper">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="password" class="form-control formRow--input js-input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onFocus="showeye();" onBlur="hideeye();">
<div id="showhide"></div>
</div>
</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you have any trouble doing it?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question by adding your code.

Comment: Yes, i don't know how to add this feature to it

Answer (score 1):

Change your field-icon css to this

```
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none
}
```

And add this to your jquery

```
$("#password-field").focusin(function () {
  $(".field-icon").show();
});

$("#password-field").focusout(function () {
  $(".field-icon").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this just hides the eye icon and the show/hide password function is thann disable

Comment: The jQuery I supplied is to be added to your existing code not replacing it, hence "And add this to your jQuery".

Comment: Thank you, i will try, the problem is, that if i leave the input field (focusout) the toggle icon also disappears, so you can't click it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this. Check if the icon is visible, if Yes -> hide it, else -> show it. And hide it at first in the CSS.

```js
var pswIcon = $(".toggle-password")

$("#password-field").on('focus blur', function() {
  $(pswIcon).is(":visible") ? $(pswIcon).hide() : $(pswIcon).show()
  })

$(pswIcon).click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```css
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container{
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fa.toggle-password {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="" action="">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="secret">
              <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work, because if you want to click in the eye, it disappears

Answer (score -1):

Check it out once.

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.inputcontainer input').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.inputcontainer').addClass('show');
    //$('.toggleplaceholder').show();
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.inputcontainer').removeClass('show');
    //$('.toggleplaceholder').hide();
  });
});*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.inputcontainer').click( function(e) {
        
        e.preventDefault(); // stops link from making page jump to the top
        e.stopPropagation(); // when you click the button, it stops the page from seeing it as clicking the body too
        $(this).addClass('show');
        
    });
    
    $('.toggleplaceholder').click( function(e) {
        
        e.stopPropagation(); // when you click within the content area, it stops the page from seeing it as clicking the body too
        
    });
    
    $('html').click( function() {
       
        $('.inputcontainer').removeClass('show');
        
    });
    
});
```

```css
.toggleplaceholder {
  display: none;
}

.show .toggleplaceholder {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputcontainer">
  <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  <span class="toggleplaceholder"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work on the OP's code as they are changing the input type from password to plain text depending on the toggle state - therefore the eye icon won't show if the state is toggled to plain text and then blured/focused again.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work, because if you want to click in the eye, it disappears

Comment: @CyberChris79 Updated the code Now. See if it helps.

Comment: may I know Why?

Comment: Because the toggle icon is not inside the input field.